# Completing vim and shell commands with arguments using input() prompt

Tags: vim, tab-completion

I have a need to receive a vim command from user and store it to a variable. The user should be able to type the command with arguments just like `Ex` mode (with auto-completion via <kbd>Tab</kbd>). I found that this can be done in two ways, by defining a custom command or by using `input()` together with `command` completion behavior:

> Completion behavior
>
> `-complete=command`   Ex command (and arguments)

The problem is that `input()` refuses to complete shell commands with arguments, although no problem if defining a custom command.

**Custom command test:**

```
:command! -nargs=+ -complete=command ExCmd let mycmd=<q-args>
```

Usage:

```
:ExCmd !ls /tmp
```

Completion works all the way while typing. I'm able to complete any vim or shell commands (like `!ls`) and file names (like `/tmp`). No problem there.

**`input()` test:**

```
:let mycmd = input("Enter a command: ", "", "command")
```

In this test you get `Enter a command:` prompt, but when typing for example `!ls` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> - nothing happens, completion doesn't work.

Am I missing something? Or is it a Vim bug?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
:let mycmd = input("Enter a command: ", "", "shellcmd")
```

to complete "shell commands"

Comment: I tried, file name completion doesn't work. Besides I want to be still able to enter normal vim commands, not only shell.

Comment: you want to auto-complete shell command name, don't you?  `Completing shell commands using input() prompt` @svlasov